# React JS ES6 with Froala Editor Configuration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, froala

I'm a newbie with ReactJS and I'm doing a project with ReactJS ES6. In my project, I use Froala Editor, it works perfectly. But now, I have a new feature requires Froala Editor adding input text, text area so Froala need more configuration. I don't know where to place configuration in ReactJS component. Here is my React component.

```
import FroalaEditor from 'react-froala-wysiwyg'
import FroalaEditorView from 'react-froala-wysiwyg/FroalaEditorView'

class RequestFormComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleModelChange = this.handleModelChange.bind(this);
        $.FroalaEditor.DefineIcon('insertInputField', {NAME: 'plus'});
        $.FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('insertInputField', {
            title: 'Insert InputField',
            focus: true,
            undo: true,
            refreshAfterCallback: true,
            callback: function () {
               this.html.insert(some input text);
            }
        });

        this.state = this._getState();
    }

    _getState() {
        return {
            content: "Some text",
            config: {
                toolbarButtons: ['undo', 'redo', 'clearFormatting', 'selectAll', 'html', 'insertInputField']
            }
        }
    }

    handleModelChange(model) {
        this.setState({content: model});
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <FroalaEditor
                 model={this.state.content}
                 onModelChange={this.handleModelChange}
                 config = {this.state.config}
            />
         )
     }
```

If I config like this, console will show error message "Cannot read property 'DefineIcon' of undefined"

I researched a lot but got nothing. 
Please give me some advices to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should import jquery:
`import $ from 'jquery';`

Answer (score 0):

You have to import jQuery.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Install jQuery by `npm i jquery -s` command.

And have to trigger the jQuery in componentDidMount method.

```
componentDidMount() {
        $.FroalaEditor.DefineIcon('insertInputField', {NAME: 'plus'});
        $.FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('insertInputField', {
            title: 'Insert InputField',
            focus: true,
            undo: true,
            refreshAfterCallback: true,
            callback: function () {
               this.html.insert(some input text);
            }
        });

        this.state = this._getState();
}
```